# Installing rgl on Ubuntu and Mac: X11 not found

Tags: r, linux, macos, rgl

I have seen this question here: [Error in loading rgl package with Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878693/error-in-loading-rgl-package-with-mac-os-x) but there is no mentioning about installation error, which is my case. I cannot install `rgl` package, using this command in `R`:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rgl")
```

The following error is displayed:

> configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
>       ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
>       * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl’

I checked this address `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library` and there is no `rgl` folder, so I cannot delete `aglrgl.so` (or `rgl.so`), which is the answer to the above-mentioned question. Can you please help me with this installation problem? Thanks.

Comment: you have to install [xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/)

Comment: Thanks, problem solved!!!

Comment: Why are you using bioconductor to install "rgl"?

Comment: To use nonlinear dimensionality reduction package which are in `RDRToolbox`. This package has `rgl` as its dependency.

Comment: @rawr please post this as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878693/error-in-loading-rgl-package-with-mac-os-x @RomanLuštrik

Comment: @raws I think the questions differ enough to be considered as two entities.

Comment: @MatinKh perhaps you should pick the solution you found that worked on mac OS X, or write your own if it's different, for future users.  This is a commonly viewed question without a green tick solution to it.  Seems worth doing.

Comment: Thank you, @FXQuantTrader for the suggestion. I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the mentioned answers are correct; however, none is for Mac.

In my case (I am a Mac user), I solved the problem by installing [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) and restarting R.

Comment: I did this, no success :/

Comment: same, do you have to run the install on XQuartz, via xterm command line? Even trying that gave me the same issues.

Answer (score 62):

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04, you might get this issue when trying to install `rgl` from CRAN:

> checking for X... no configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.

> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’

Credit is due to this blog which solved my problems at installing `rgl`:

```
http://solaimurugan.blogspot.ca/2015/09/3d-data-visualization-using-r-configure.html
```

In case the link above disappears, the solution, as outlined in the blog is:

```
sudo apt-get install xorg 
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev 
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

More recently, installing rgl on a fresh ubuntu 16.04 install also requires a further step (as noted in the comments below), if you get this error:

> fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory

This is solved with:

```
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
```

Then installing `rgl` from CRAN should just work.

Comment: I did need `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you and the blogger.

Comment: After following your procedure which helped me fix the first couple of error messages - I needed `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` after getting the R installation error message `fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: @AnthonyEbert, thanks, this last `libfreetype6-dev` did the trick for me too, the 3 libs in the post were not enough.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 after installing `xorg`, `libx11-dev`, `libglu1-mesa-dev` and `libfreetype6-dev`.

Comment: Also worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.1 after installing the same packages as @apitsch. I needed each of them.

Answer (score 32):

On Ubuntu, what worked for me was to install the package directly from the command line:

`sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl`

(We have a strange setup here, so YMMV)

Comment: Note that this may install an outdated version.

Answer (score 12):

On CentOS, what finally did the trick was installing libpng-dev:

```
sudo yum install libpng-devel.x86_64
```

Prior to this, I installed xorg, libx11, the mesa GL library, and freeglut.

```
sudo yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64 xorg-x11-server-devel.x86_64 
sudo yum install libX11.x86_64 libX11-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install mesa-libGL mesa-libGL-devel mesa-libGLU mesa-libGLU-devel
sudo yum install freeglut.x86_64 freeglut-devel.x86_64
```

The way I finally figured out what was missing was to try compiling from source (download the tar.gz at [cran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/index.html)), and examining the config.log after ./configure failed.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about Mac case but on Windows I faced issues downloading the same rgl Package. Installing the RGL requires the devtools package

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install.packages("rgl")
library(rgl)
```

Comment: For my case, installing xquartz [http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/] solved the problem. See the comment thread above.

Comment: On Linux, I've solved this problem by installing the `build-dep` and `r-cran-rgl` packages. Installing the `devtools` R package may have also been essential in my case, but I really can't tell.

Answer (score 2):

Took me a long time to figure this out on the [RHEL 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux]. The following packages are required:

```
libpng12-devel.x86_64
ImageMagick-c++-devel.x86_64
mesa-libGLU-devel.x86_64
libselinux-devel.x86_64
xorg-x11-apps
```

Answer (score 1):

On OpenSuse

```
sudo zypper install xorg-x11-devel
sudo zypper install glu-devel
```