# how to install "ks" package on a remote server

Tags: r, package, x11, rgl

I was trying to install the R package `ks` on a remote server. However, I received the following error info:

```
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package ‘ks’
```

Since it is a remote server, I cannot not install `X11`. Is there a way that I could install `ks` without `X11`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how this works. *Of course* remote servers, headless or not, can have X11 -- they would "export" their display to, say, your machine.  And often X11 is "just" needed for font metrics of other graphic displays such as png or pdf.

ks and rgl are fairly common. Maybe you can even install them as binary packages -- at least Debian/Ubuntu have them, and other distros may too.

Comment: Thanks. Still I cannot solve the configuration issue with X11. I see my problem similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package.  However I cannot install xquartz on the server. Also similar to this post: https://github.com/thibautjombart/treescape/issues/69, where rgl cannot be installed because of X11.

Comment: rgl originally required OpenGL, which requires X11 on Unix and MacOS systems.  Nowadays it can work entirely in WebGL which has no such requirement, but it would be a lot of tedious work to remove the OpenGL dependencies.  It's unlikely to change unless someone volunteers to do the work.