# How to solve dependence issues and error installing qpcR package?

Tags: r, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I cannot install qpcR package, using this command in R:

```
install.packages("qpcR")
```

Apparently, everything looks fine initially:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/emanuel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/qpcR_1.4-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4303726 bytes (4.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘qpcR’ ...
** package ‘qpcR’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-      protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c registerDynamicSymbol.c -o registerDynamicSymbol.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c smth.c -o smth.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o qpcR.so registerDynamicSymbol.o smth.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
```

And then things starts to going wrong:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: recipe for target 'qpcR.so' failed
make: *** [qpcR.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘qpcR’
* removing ‘/home/emanuel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/qpcR’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘qpcR’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpOPiQkB/downloaded_packages’
```

Additional (maybe) relevant info:

- Before the lines presented above, I was having trouble with another qpcR dependence, the rgl package, and I solved trying all the suggestions from another question: "[Error in installing rgl package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820865/error-in-installing-rgl-package)".
- I made a brief search about:  "-llpack", "-lblas", "qpcR.so" .Unfortunately nothing seems (to me at least) to be related to my specific problem.
- I using Mint with these specifications: Linux version 4.8.0-53-generic (buildd@lgw01-56) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu
- R version 3.4.4
- R studio Version 1.1.453

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Something along the lines of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/736684/336238)?

Comment: Yes! the command lines @Akarsh Jain post here is on the link you recommend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

satisfy the dependencies using this command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

hope this helps (Y)

Comment: Solved! Thanks @Akarsh Jain!