# How to install "biotools" In R 3.6.1?

Tags: r

Having trouble installing "biotools" under R 3.6.1 on Mac.

Get this output:

```
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] can't find package BWidget.

Error: unable to load R code in package ‘rpanel’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rpanel’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rpanel’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rpanel’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rpanel’ is not available for package ‘biotools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/biotools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘biotools’ had non-zero exit status
```

Tried to install missing package "BWidget" as noted in error above, but got this message:

> install.packages("BWidget")
>       Warning message:
>       package 'BWidget' is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

As noted in one of the other postings here, and, after checking, I do not have a "lock" file.

Suggestions on how to get library biotools and dependencies installed?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21729873

Comment: I tried to use macports to download BWidget. It said it installed it with about 30 other depdencies, but RStudio still barfs the same error...

Comment: Perhaps it's nothing, but have you restarted rstudio since installing BWidget? I don't know but if it updates path or other envvars, rstudio won't see the change without a restart. Other than that, I don't know ...

Comment: Here's the solution that worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729873/r-having-trouble-installing-rpanel

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but I was having this BWidget problem and none of the answers around here worked except for this one found here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2006-October/003301.html

With some updates to what worked for me, this is the solution:

download BWidget from
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=12883
once you get the archive BWidget-1.9.14.tar in your downloads folder go onto Terminal and do the following:

```
mv /some_download_path/BWidget-1.9.14.tar /usr/local/lib

cd ./usr/local/lib

tar zxf BWidget-1.9.14.tar.gz
```

***** Because I'm on a university computer, I had to **cd ../** until I got to the base folder that had both **./Users/MyUserName/Downloads/Bwidget-1.9.14.tar** and **./usr/local/lib**

*(if this response is not formatted properly, please fix it for me - I'm not very good at this)*